# pytest-variables: how get "variables" without declaring variables argument in test function prototype

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using pytest-variables (see https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-variables) to pass some variables by the command line as below:

```
 pytest **--variables** my_json_file.
```

How can I get then this variable in all my tests without declaring it as argument in every function ? 
Below the way I am accessing to the variable for now:

```py
@pytest.mark.run()
def test_one (variables):
    helper_function_1 (variables)
    helper_function_2 (variables)

@pytest.mark.run()
def test_two (variables):
    helper_function_3 (variables)
    helper_function_4 (variables)
```

Is there anyway not to repeat this "variables" 's declaration in every test ?
Thank you for any help.